# Pre-populating Find/Replace Dialog Box (Ctrl+H)

Tags: excel, vba

I want the user to be able to change the starting number of a const without accessing the code through the replace bar(Ctrl+h). I managed to write the code that opens it, but I have no clue how can I write a code that will input to the find field and replace field.

right now my code is just one line that opens the replace bar:

```
    Sub test()
    Application.SendKeys "^(h)"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Use an input box to get the value from the user, then call the `Range.Replace` method from your code, with the user-supplied vale: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  It will open the find/replace dialog pre-populated with what you pass as the arguments.

`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaReplace).Show arg1:= "find", arg2:= "replace"`

Potential arguments here, take a look at the documentation for replace linked below for what argument values to use.  The function is "different" but utilizes the same constants, such as look_at in the 'Dialogs' function uses the same arguments as LookAt in 'Replace' function.

`xlDialogFormulaReplace find_text, replace_text, look_at, look_by, active_cell, match_case, match_byte`

For finding values.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

For replacing values
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace

From your comment it would appear you want this to be entirely automated, without any user intervention.  If thats the case, utilize the Replace() function in excel.

Example usage, simpler than the article and doesn't require you to set a bool value: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace "find", "replace", xlWhole`

How you plan on triggering the code is up to you. :)

**NOTE: Replacements via VBA can't be undone using CTRL-Z**